# What does the shadow do?

Tags: ramble-planet

In the desert, I came across a mysterious shifting cloud, that looks suspiciously like my swarm of nanobots did before I interfaced with a crewmember.

If you try to interact with it, it becomes humanoid and follows you for a short distance before vanishing.  What's up with this?  Can I do anything useful with it?

[image: What's this mysterious shadow?]

[image: The shadow assumes humanoid form and follows behind you]

[image: It's following me!]

Answer (score -1):

The shadow does not actually help you find PARTS or other items. However, there is something kind of special about him. Feel free to experiment with him and you might find an interesting but unnecessary secret.